# Application of Lagrange Theorem to the polynomial $g(x)-h(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is known that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients of degree $n$ has at most $n$ distinct roots.

I want to prove the following statement by using the above theorem: Let $g(x),h(x)$ be polynomial both of degree $n$ with real coefficients. Let $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n,c_{n+1}$ be distinct elements such that $g(c_i)=h(c_i)$, for each $1 \leq i \leq n+1$. Then $g(x)=h(x)$, for all $x$.

My proof is as follows: Define $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$. Then $\deg(f(x))\leq n$. Then either $\deg(f(x))=n$ of $\deg(f(x))\leq n-1$. If $\deg(f(x))=n$, then $f(x)$ has at most $n$ distinct roots. But $f(c_i)=g(c_i)-h(c_i)=0$, for each $i=1,2,\cdots,n,n+1$, so there is a unique integer $1\leq j\leq n+1$ such that $c_j$ is not one of the $n$ distinct roots of $f(x)$. I don't know how can I proceed from here.

How can I conclude from this that $g(x)=h(x)$, for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\deg(f(x))\leqslant n$, if $f(x)$ is not the null polynomial, then it has at most $n$ distinct roots. But we know that it has $n+1$ distinct roots. So, $f(x)$ is the null polynomial, and that means that $g(x)=h(x)$.

Comment: So this means that if it were not true that $f(x)=0$, then $f(x)\neq 0$ and so from this we have that $f$ has at most $n$ roots. But since $f(c_i)=0$, for each $i$, then there are integers $1\leq i,j \leq n +1$, such that $c_i=c_j$, for $i\neq j$. But this contradicts the initial assumption that all the $c_i$'s were all distincts. Hence, $f(x)=0,\forall x$. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: OK, I got it! Thank you very much for your response!